# Screen out data in specific periods of time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The original 'df' is:

```
                     value   id                                                                       
2014-02-28 09:00:00  10660    a
2014-02-28 09:01:00  10697    a
2014-02-28 09:02:00  10672    b
2014-02-28 09:03:00  10667    b
2014-02-28 09:04:00  10650    c
...
2020-04-10 14:55:00   6983    d
2020-04-10 14:56:00   6988    d
2020-04-10 14:57:00   6991    e
2020-04-10 14:58:00   6979    e
2020-04-10 14:59:00   6984    f
```

The format of index is 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'. Its type is 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'.

The time of df contains everyday from 2014 to 2020.

I want to find all data in January, February, March and April of every year. Sorry I am not able to show an expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.index.month.isin([1,2,3,4])]
```

Comment: Thank you. I only knew pandas.Series.dt.month before.